# Why doesn't email gets returned from Facebook.Rest.Api.Users.GetInfo()?

Tags: email, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook

I'm using .NET MVC 3 and I'm trying to get users email from Facebook connect. I have searched around and feels like I have tried everything, but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

This is my loginbutton where I set email permission

```
<fb:login-button perms="email, offline_access" autologoutlink="false" />
```

And this is my server-side call for getting user information

```
var user = Api.Users.GetInfo(GetUserID());
```

In debug mode I can see that user is set and authenticated, but email is not set, even though I've set "email" as a permission and after user has granted. Please, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

TIA

*Bump*

It's been three days and still no response. I was thinking, do I have to registrate user to get access for email? Seems kinda odd if that's the case, since user grant email permission. Any kind of though is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed (Web.Helpers) Facebook.Helpers, and it worked like a charm. Even though I've followed fackbooks guidlines, I must have done something wrong. Still weird that I got the user informationen, but not the email.